# TypeError: push is not detected as a function for address payable dynamic array

Tags: addresses, arrays, payable

I'm trying to add the manager address to the playes array. I get the following error:

> TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable[] storage ref.

This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

contract Lottery{
    address public manager;
    uint public value;
    address payable[] private players;
    
    constructor() payable {
            manager = msg.sender;
            value = msg.value;
    }
    
    function enter() public payable {
            require(value > 0.01 ether);
            players.push(manager);
    }
    
    function random() private view returns (uint){
            return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));
    }
    
    function pickWinner() public{
            uint index = random() % players.length;
            players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to push a non-payable address to the array: `manager` is not `payable`. You'll need to change the type of `manager` to `address payable`:

```
address payable public manager;

function enter() public payable {
  require(value > 0.01 ether);
  players.push(manager);
}
```

Simply adding `msg.sender` (e.g. `players.push(msg.sender)`) to the array will work fine, since it's already `payable`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this issue now, since solidity v0.8.0 you also need to declare msg.sender as payable:

```
manager = payable(msg.sender)
```

or

```
players.push(payable(msg.sender));
```